# Push notification issue on Setting Screen

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In my app, **Push notifications** are enabled. Can we know from the app wether the push notification switch in the setting is on or off for the app ?

I am using this code, which its returning 7 every time :

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

Comment: @JackyBoy: yes, but the subject is outdated. The solution no longer works..

Comment: There is a more updated answer below, from 2012.

Comment: i have check this link after that i have updated the question.Not able to find the solution yet.Any info regarding that